# Show that $2^n(\cos^n(\frac{2\pi}{9})+\cos^n(\frac{4\pi}{9})+\cos^n(\frac{8\pi}{9}))\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> 1. Let $$a_n=2^n\left[\cos^n\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{9}\right)+\cos^n\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{9}\right)+\cos^n\left(\dfrac{8\pi}{9}\right)\right].$$ Show that $a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

> 2. Find the last digit of $a_{10^6}$.

My progress:

1. I believe it can be solved by expressing $a_n$ as a linear recurrence by using the cubic equation $x^3-3x+1=0$ which has the roots $x_1=2\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{9}\right)$, $x_2=2\cos\left(\dfrac{4\pi}{9}\right)$, $x_3=2\cos\left(\dfrac{8\pi}{9}\right)$. I'm just not really sure how to connect $a_n$ to this cubic equation.
2. I guess that if you could find a linear recurrence to $a_n$, the last digit would be cyclic and could be found that way. I was hoping to solve it without using computer work, but maybe that's tough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As shown in $(10)$ below, $x_1=2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)$, $x_2=2\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{9}\right)$, and $x_3=2\cos\left(\frac{8\pi}{9}\right)$ all satisfy
$$
x^3-3x+1=0\tag{1}
$$
As shown in $(13)$ below, the sequence $a_n=c_1x_1^n+c_2x_2^n+c_3x_3^n$ satisfies
$$
\begin{align}
a_n&=3a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}
\end{align}\tag{2}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
x_1&=e^{2\pi i/9}+e^{-2\pi i/9}\\
x_2&=e^{4\pi i/9}+e^{-4\pi i/9}\\
x_3&=e^{8\pi i/9}+e^{-8\pi i/9}
\end{align}\tag{3}
$$
Thus, as shown in $(7)$ below, being the sum of the ninth roots of unity minus the sum of the third roots of unity,
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3=0\tag{4}
$$
Using equation $(8)$ below, we get
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=6\tag{5}
$$
Therefore, we get
$$
\begin{align}
a_0&=x_1^0+x_2^0+x_3^0=3\\
a_1&=x_1^1+x_2^1+x_3^1=0\\
a_2&=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=6
\end{align}\tag{6}
$$
Eqations $(2)$ and $(6)$ show that $a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\ge0$.

---

**Why $x_k$ Satisfies (1)**

As noted above, the sum of $x_k$ is the difference of the sum of the ninth roots of unity and the sum of the third roots of unity, and therefore $0$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
&x_1+x_2+x_3\\[6pt]
&=\small\left(e^{2\pi i/9}+e^{16\pi i/9}\right)+\left(e^{4\pi i/9}+e^{14\pi i/9}\right)+\left(e^{8\pi i/9}+e^{10\pi i/9}\right)\\
&=\small\left(e^{0\pi i/9}+e^{2\pi i/9}+e^{4\pi i/9}+e^{6\pi i/9}+e^{8\pi i/9}+e^{10\pi i/9}+e^{12\pi i/9}+e^{14\pi i/9}+e^{16\pi i/9}\right)\\
&-\small\left(e^{0\pi i/9}+e^{6\pi i/9}+e^{12\pi i/9}\right)\\
&=0-0\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$

Squaring and subtracting $2$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
x_1^2-2=\left(e^{2\pi i/9}+e^{-2\pi i/9}\right)^2-2&=e^{4\pi i/9}+e^{-4\pi i/9}=x_2\\
x_2^2-2=\left(e^{4\pi i/9}+e^{-4\pi i/9}\right)^2-2&=e^{8\pi i/9}+e^{-8\pi i/9}=x_3\\
x_3^2-2=\left(e^{8\pi i/9}+e^{-8\pi i/9}\right)^2-2&=e^{2\pi i/9}+e^{-2\pi i/9}=x_1
\end{align}\tag{8}
$$
Squaring each equation in $(8)$ and subtracting $2$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
x_1^4-4x_1^2+2&=x_2^2-2=x_3\\
x_2^4-4x_2^2+2&=x_3^2-2=x_1\\
x_3^4-4x_3^2+2&=x_1^2-2=x_2\\
\end{align}\tag{9}
$$
Adding $(8)$, $(9)$, and $x_k=x_k$, we get (using subscripts mod $3$)
$$
x_k^4-3x_k^2+x_k=\overbrace{(x_k^4-4x_k+2)}^{x_{k-1}\text{ from }(9)}+\overbrace{(x_k^2-2)}^{x_{k+1}\text{ from }(8)}+x_k=x_1+x_2+x_3=0\tag{10}
$$

Since $x_k\ne0$, equation $(10)$ says that $x_k$ must satisfy $(1)$.

---

**Why Do The Roots Of (1) Satisfy (2)**

Any root of $x^3-3x+1=0$ also satisfies 
$$
x^n=3x^{n-2}-x^{n-3}\tag{11}
$$
That is, $a_n=x^n$ satisfies $(2)$

Any linear combination of solutions to $(2)$ is also a solution to $(2)$. Thus, we get that
$$
a_n=c_1x_1^n+c_2x_2^n+c_3x_3^n\tag{12}
$$
is a solution of $(2)$ for any $c_k$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=c_1x_1^n+c_2x_2^n+c_3x_3^n\\
&=c_1(3x_1^{n-2}-x_1^{n-3})+c_2(3x_2^{n-2}-x_2^{n-3})+c_3(3x_3^{n-2}-x_3^{n-3})\\
&=3(c_1x_1^{n-2}+c_2x_2^{n-2}+c_3x_3^{n-2})-(c_1x_1^{n-3}+c_2x_2^{n-3}+c_3x_3^{n-3})\\
&=3a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Last Digit of $a_{10^6}$**

Brute force computation shows that mod $10$, $a_n$ has a period of $434$. Since $10^6\equiv64\pmod{434}$ and $a_{64}\equiv6\pmod{10}$, $a_{10^6}\equiv6\pmod{10}$. Since $a_{10^6}=x_1^{10^6}+x_2^{10^6}+x_3^{10^6}\ge0$, the last digit of $a_{10^6}$ is $6$.

Comment: I believe the OPs question 1/ is "how to connect $a_n$ to this cubic equation".  A generalization, or explanation, or even a reference link that explains the connection between (1) and (2) seems to be what the poster is asking for, and I would be interested as well.

Comment: @DanielV: Ah, I missed that. I actually missed the equation in the question and derived it myself. I removed it when I saw it in the question. I then missed that the OP wanted to see the derivation. I will add it back :-)

Comment: As DanielV said, I'm interested in how you got to (2). I'm not really sure, but (7) and (8) only shows how you got to (1) right? How do you use (1) to get the recurrence equation (2)?

Comment: @Snape: Yes. I finally read your question again, and saw that I misunderstood DanielV's comment. I've added the explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The observation on the zeros of $x^3 - 3 x + 1$ means that:
$$
1 - \frac{12}{z} + \frac{8}{z^3}
$$
has $2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{9}, 2 \cos \frac{4 \pi}{9}, 2 \cos \frac{8 \pi}{9}$ as inverses of its zeros,
which means that the recurrence:
$$
a_{n + 3} - 12 a_{n + 2} + 8 a_n = 0
$$
has general solution:
$$
a_n
  = c_1 2^n \cos^n \frac{2 \pi}{9}
     + c_2 2^n \cos^n \frac{4 \pi}{9}
     + c_3 2^n \cos^n \frac{8 \pi}{9}
$$
From the recurrence it is obvious that $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$ if $a_0, a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Would need to check those three cases of the above... in any case, $a_0 = 3$ is an integer. One down, two to go.

Comment: The recurrence $a_{n+3}-12a_{n+2}+8a_n=0$ does not have $2^n\cos^n\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)$, $2^n\cos^n\left(\frac{4\pi}{9}\right)$, or $2^n\cos^n\left(\frac{8\pi}{9}\right)$ as particular solutions. Those, however, are solutions to $a_{n+3}-3a_{n+1}+a_n=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_1=2\cos(\dfrac{2\pi}{9}),x_2=2\cos(\dfrac{4\pi}{9}),x_3=2\cos(\dfrac{8\pi}{9})$ and

$$\sigma_1=x_1+x_2+x_3=0$$
$$\sigma_2=x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1=-3$$
$$\sigma_3= x_1x_2x_3=-1.$$

Let $a_k=x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k$. Then, according to [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities),

$$a_k=\sigma_1 a_{k-1}-\sigma_2 a_{k-2}+ \sigma_3 a_{k-3}=3a_{k-2}- a_{k-3}\qquad k\geq3$$

$a_1=0, a_2=\sigma_1^2-2\sigma_2=6, a_3= \sigma_1 a_2-\sigma_2 a_1+3\sigma_3=-3 $, so $a_n\in\Bbb Z$.

As for $a_n\equiv b_n\pmod{10}$, it is a **periodic sequence**.

$$b_4=-2, b_5=3,b_6=-3,b_7=1,b_8=-2,b_9=6,b_{10}=3, b_{11}=0,b_{12}=3,b_{13}=-3,\\ b_{14}=-1,b_{15}=-2,b_{16}=0,b_{17}=5,b_{18}=2,b_{19}=5, \\b_{20}=1,b_{21}=3,b_{22}=-2,b_{23}=-2, b_{24}=1,b_{25}=-4,b_{26}=5,b_{27}=-3,\\b_{28}=-1,b_{29}=-4,b_{30}=0,b_{31}=-1, b_{32}=4,b_{33}=-3,b_{34}=3,\\ b_{35}=-3, b_{36}=2,b_{37}=-2,b_{38}=-1, b_{39}=2,b_{40}=1,b_{41}=-3,b_{42}=1,b_{43}=0,\\b_{44}=-4,b_{45}=-1,b_{46}=-2,b_{47}=1,b_{48}=5,b_{49}=5,b_{50}=4,b_{51}=0, b_{52}=-3,\\b_{53}=-4,$$

Comment: With this, we can show that for integer $ n>4 $, 

$ a_n \equiv a_{n + 434} $ (with the help of Excel). So $ a_{10^6} \equiv a_{64} \equiv \boxed{6} $

Comment: @GohPiHan  $434$?  terrible!

Comment: Got a better method?

Comment: How did you use Excel to get the period? Isn't there a more delicate way to find it?